# How can i set the image below the text. while changing the width of the browser

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS code for the image and text while decreasing the browser width the image overlaps to the text(designation)

```css
.timeline-logo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.timeline-logo > img{
    width: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.experience-designation {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Punit! Please include a minimal code example that can reproduce your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you share with us your html?